# Mongodb sharding performance issue

Tags: performance, mongodb, sharding

**Test** :
- insert 200 images (300-800Ko/img) using directly a *replica set*
- insert 200 images (300-800ko/img) using the *same replica set as shard*.

I realize that these operations have a really different execution time ...
- with *replica set* : 200 pictures in **around 30 sec**.
- with *sharding* : **around 3sec./picture** => **around 7- 8 minutes** for these 200 pictures !!!

**==> I really don't understand why these inserts are so slow with the sharding ... <==**

**Conditions** :
- Php driver
- GridFS : only the fs.chunks sharded
- write concern : majority
- only 1 thread : with PHP, I parse an array that contains path to pictures, and then I store the picture in MongoDB using GridFS.

**Ressources** :
(all servers are OpenVZ VM's on a Proxmox plate-form (all on the same machine (for test)))
3 *mongod* : 6Go RAM (50% while inserting), 1CPU (99% idle while inserting...)
2 *arbiters* : 512Mo RAM (100Mo used), 1CPU(100% idle ...)
1 *config* : 2Go RAM (200Mo used), 1 CPU(100% idle ...)
1 *mongos* : 512Mo RAM (100Mo used), 1CPU (98%idle while inserting...)

**Notes** :
while inserting *with sharding* :
- ~1->5% CPU utilization for all mongod, mongos and config_svr instances
- ~5% RAM utilization for mongos/config_svr
- ~50% for mongod
- ***network throughput*** (metrics taken on the mongod): mongos <--> primary mongod : ***~300Kb/s***

while inserting *without sharding* (replica set directly) :
- ***network throughput*** (metrics taken on the mongod): hosting pictures server <--> primary mongod : ***~30Mb/s***

***Php class*** : [pastebin.com_[mongodb-class]](http://pastebin.com/ExbKa03w) (that contains all the code to interact with MongoDB)
I added at the top of the class :
`mongoLog::setLevel(mongoLog::all)`
`mongoLog::setModule(mongoLog::all)`
`display_errors=1`
`error_reporting=-1`
*The client directly calls the **storefile()** method of this class...*
The ***result page*** is here : [pastebin.com_[resultPage]](http://pastebin.com/LvtBeA8x)

Documents inserted are even simple as: **MongoID, picture_binaries_data**
I've ***no meta-data***, only what MongoDB generates during the storing process.

Here's the result of **sh.status()** on the mongos :

```
    mongos> sh.status()
    --- Sharding Status ---
      sharding version: {
            "_id" : 1,
            "version" : 3,
            "minCompatibleVersion" : 3,
            "currentVersion" : 4,
            "clusterId" : ObjectId("518372e807be4a15fb391fab")
    }
      shards:
            {  "_id" : "rs0",  "host" : "rs0/192.168.36.101:27017,192.168.36.102:27017,192.168.36.103:27017" }
      databases:
            {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
            {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "rs0" }
            {  "_id" : "bepics_gallery",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "rs0" }
            {  "_id" : "bepics_images",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "rs0" }
                    bepics_images.fs.chunks
                            shard key: { "files_id" : 1 }
                            chunks:
                                    rs0     9
                            { "files_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183926028d40965190000ea") } on : rs0 { "t" : 1, "i" : 1 }
                            { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183926028d40965190000ea") } -->> { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183a1be28d409051e000004") } on : rs0 { "t" : 1, "i" : 3 }
                            { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183a1be28d409051e000004") } -->> { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183a2a728d409051e00008f") } on : rs0 { "t" : 1, "i" : 5 }
                            { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183a2a728d409051e00008f") } -->> { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183b70328d409cc1e00008f") } on : rs0 { "t" : 1, "i" : 7 }
                            { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183b70328d409cc1e00008f") } -->> { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183c6f728d409e526000037") } on : rs0 { "t" : 1, "i" : 9 }
                            { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183c6f728d409e526000037") } -->> { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183c76028d409e526000076") } on : rs0 { "t" : 1, "i" : 11 }
                            { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183c76028d409e526000076") } -->> { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183c7cb28d409ea2600001f") } on : rs0 { "t" : 1, "i" : 13 }
                            { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183c7cb28d409ea2600001f") } -->> { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183c84e28d409ea2600006d") } on : rs0 { "t" : 1, "i" : 15 }
                            { "files_id" : ObjectId("5183c84e28d409ea2600006d") } -->> { "files_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs0 { "t" : 1, "i" : 16 }
```

To connect to the cluster, I use a MySQL table where I store servers configuration like ip, port, priority, RS_name, ...
In ***repica set archi.*** => I build the connection-pool with the *name of the replica set*, and the *3 first servers*, sorted by *priority*.
In ***sharding archi.*** => I build the connection-pool with *all mongos*.
(all adresses in connections-pool are formatted like ip:port)

Can anyone help me to solve it or explain it to me ?

Comment: I really cannot read that image, can you copy the contents of the console and post it somewhere?